# Query to make rows into column values without using PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query and gives the result also shown below.

```
  SELECT      
      SUM(atm) atm,SUM(cc) cc,SUM(csh) csh ,SUM(chk) chk
    FROM  sales                 
    WHERE repId= 9000
          AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00'
```

[image: Query result]

How to modify the query without using PIVOT to rerun the result as shown below.
   [image: Query Result]

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
SELECT  'atm' type, SUM(atm) Amount  FROM  sales                 
  WHERE repId= 9000 AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'cc' type, SUM(cc) Amount  FROM  sales                 
  WHERE repId= 9000 AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'csh' type, SUM(csh) Amount  FROM  sales                 
  WHERE repId= 9000 AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'chk' type, SUM(chk) Amount  FROM  sales                 
  WHERE repId= 9000 AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00'
```

or, using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE(atm,cc,csh,chk) AS
   (SELECT  SUM(atm),SUM(cc),SUM(csh),SUM(chk) FROM sales                 
    WHERE repId= 9000 AND DATEADD(dd,0,DATEDIFF(dd,0,idate)) ='2013-08-25 00:00:00' )
SELECT  'atm' Type,atm Amount FROM CTE
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc' ,cc  FROM CTE
UNION ALL SELECT 'csh',csh FROM CTE
UNION ALL SELECT 'chk',chk FROM CTE
```

Comment: Is there any better method than using UNION ALL?

Comment: I don't think there is, but when you are using the Common Table Expression version, as shown above, the three `SELECT`s do cause any extra work for the SQL server. Theoretically `UNION ALL` is 'cheaper' than a `UNION` but, with a total of three rows in this example, you will definitely not notice any difference, so in this case you could also use `UNION` instead.